# ARKit planeDectection continues even after setting planeDetection as empty

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

In my application, I am using ARKit's delegate methods to automatic surface/ plane detection:

1. `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for
   anchor: ARAnchor) {}` to add planes.
2. `renderer(_ renderer:
   SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {}`
   to update planes.
3. `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRemove
   node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {}` to remove planes.

My configuration is set to enable horizontal plane detection as:

```
configuration?.planeDetection = .horizontal
```

This works fine and I am able to detect and create plane Nodes where surfaces are being detected.

There are two issues here:

1. As per Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration.planedetection), I should be able to set planeDetection to `[]` if I want to stop horizontal plane detection. Within a button I am trying to do that I am setting planeDetection to empty, however on running the application planes are still being detected within the app. Meaning, `renderer(didAdd: )` and `renderer(didUpdate: )` methods are still operational. To make sure I even printed their results and they are operational even after disabling planeDetection. 
   **Am I doing something wrong? What would be the sure shot way of stopping my `renderer(didAdd: )` and `renderer(didUpdate: )` methods at will?**
2. There are situations wherein two planes are detected at the same place. At times, these two planes coalesce, but at other times they do not. **In terms of best practices, how can this situation be avoided?** I tried detecting if there already is a planeNode within my scene's frustum, don't add a new plane, however that also poses some issues especially when there is a plane added, but later another plane was supposed to be added at the same place and the latter was the one delegate functions are updating. In this situation, the latter is not even added since the former is still within my frustum. Hope this is clear. **Just wanted to know how best can this situation be averted/ avoided?**

Body of renderer methods is the usual:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
    let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x),
                         height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))
    ...
}
```

Pointers much appreciated.

Note:

> The way I am currently thinking of managing both issues is to
>   introduce a Bool which will be changed by a button - this will decide
>   where renderer(didAdd: ) works or stops working. (I will not use the
>   Bool on renderer(didUpdate: ) since it needs to update the already
>   detected planes. Additionally, I will use the *frustum* logic so that
>   only one plane is detected at one place. Lastly, I will track the
>   number of updates my planes are having, if that doesn't reach a
>   threshold, let's say 5, I will remove all those plane whose number of
>   updates could not reach 5 from the scene.  This might add some
>   stability to User Experience, however I strongly feel that this will
>   add both much complexity and more constraints than user would like to
>   have.

Am I thinking in the right direction? In dire need of some better logic here guys.

Comment: I think you need to call `run()` on the session again after making change to its configuration.

Comment: Jeez! How can I forget to do that :( Thanks much, that was it. I called `run()` and it works. Any idea on the second part of my question?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best practice but I wrote up an answer on your second question the other day, you can have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980670/arkit-floating-planes/47982357#47982357

Comment: Did take a look, will try this logic. Meanwhile if you could combine the two comments of your and post and answer I will check that, since actually these two combined make up for a good answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to call the [`run(_:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2875735-run) method again after making changes to the configuration of your `ARSession` in order for it to work.

2) I'm not sure if this is the best practice but you can try manually checking whether the planes overlap by doing the following:

- Project your planes on the xz-plane. Since ARKit only supports horizontal surface detection, this should be fairly easy.
- Check whether your planes collide, using a 2D collision detection method.
- Remove either one of the colliding planes if a portion higher than a certain threshold of the planes are colliding. You may also want to check whether the two planes are close enough to each other in 3D.